# Getting "Cannot set readonly property: value for class: java.lang.String" while modifying the XML

Tags: xml, groovy

I have the following XML

```
<test>
<one>
    <one1>120</one1>
    <one2>115</one2>
</one>
<two>
    <two1>100</two1>
    <two2>50</two2>
</two>
```

I need to change the values to the following

```
<test>
<one>
    <one1>121</one1>
    <one2>116</one2>
</one>
<two>
    <two1>101</two1>
    <two2>51</two2>
</two>
```

My XML is stored locally. I have written the following groovy code to modify the XML

```
def xmlFile = "D:/Service/something.xml"
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
xml.one[0].one1[0].each { 
  it.value = "201"
}
xml.one[0].one2[0].each { 
  it.value = "116"
}

xml.two[0].two1[0].each { 
  it.value = "101"
}
xml.two[0].two2[0].each { 
  it.value = "51"
}

new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)
```

But i am getting this error

> Caused by: groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: value for class: java.lang.String

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node `.value()` [is a method of the Node class](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html#value%28%29).  You are looking for the corresponding method `setValue` method.

```
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText('<test><one><one1>120</one1><one2>115</one2></one><two><two1>100</two1><two2>50</two2></two></test>');
xml.one[0].one1[0].setValue(121);
xml.one[0].one2[0].setValue(116);
xml.two[0].two1[0].setValue(101);
xml.two[0].two2[0].setValue(51);
```

Comment: After doing this, do i need to do this also new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(xmlFile))).print(xml)...?

Comment: If you want to write it back out into a file.

Comment: If i do that then it is writing to a file, but it is adding lots of white spaces... How to avoid it?

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142967/how-to-write-an-xml-to-file-with-just-a-parser-instance for how to avoid all the whitespace.