# Jenkins - how to set an XML attribute and then write back to an XML file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Following on from my [last post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545854/jenkins-xmlparser-reports-no-such-field-found-for-attribute-for-root-node), where I was shown how to read an XML attribute, my last task is now to **set** the attribute, e.g. I'll be incrementing the read attribute and then writing back.

So, again I have the following XML file:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget android-versionCode="16" id="com.mycomp.myapp" ios-CFBundleVersion="15" version="1.3.0.b4" windows-packageVersion="1.2.6.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>My app description</description>
    <author>mycom.com.au</author>
```

And I learnt that the following, as per the help did not work:

```
def xml = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/config.xml"
def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
def version = rootNode.@version
```

but the following would:

```
def version = rootNode.attributes()['version']
```

I now seem to have the same problem writing the attribute back.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142967/how-to-write-an-xml-to-file-with-just-a-parser-instance) I tried the following to set the attribute:

```
 def filePath = "${env.WORKSPACE}/config.xml"
 def xml = readFile filePath
 def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)         
 rootNode.@version = "12345"         
 def writer = new FileWriter(filePath)
 new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(rootNode)
```

But I get a similar error to when I was trying to read the attribute:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such field found: field groovy.util.Node version
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.unclassifiedField(SandboxInterceptor.java:425)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onSetAttribute(SandboxInterceptor.java:447)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$9.call(Checker.java:405)
at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedSetAttribute(Checker.java:411)
```

I did try this in Groovy playground, and it did seem to work, however not here in Jenkins.

So, it looks once again the `.@version` syntax is not working, and I just cannot fins an alternative call (like there was to get the attribute) to set the attribute.

How can I do this?

Comment: I also updated your other question regarding attribute access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more testing i found out, we can simply use the `@` selector inside the `[]` access (Edit: Its called [map notation](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)), seems the script sandbox can handle this. It translates in `getAt()` and `putAt()` under the hood which jenkins will allow to be approved.

```groovy
node() {
    def xml = readFile "${env.WORKSPACE}/config.xml"
    def rootNode = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
    print rootNode['@version']
    rootNode['@version'] = 123
    print rootNode['@version']
}
```

Result

```
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/xmltest
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] readFile
[Pipeline] echo
1.3.0.b4
[Pipeline] echo
123
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: thank you very much once again! The above works 100%! I will make a note of these syntaxes for the future.